# add_index for a single column twice rails migration active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, indexing, migration, rails-activerecord

I have to run a query where a single column is called twice .

```
Transaction.where("datetime >= ? && datetime <= ?", params[:date_one], :params[:date_two])
```

Now while indexing this is the basic we do

```
add_index :transactions, :datetime
```

Now my question is can I do something like.....

```
add_index :transactions, [:datetime, :datetime]
```

Will it really speedup the search or benefit performance wise. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do that. adding index to column speeds up queries to that column. It does not matter how many times you use this column in your query, only the presence or absence of index matters. Also, you can rewrite your query like this:

```
   Transaction.where("datetime BETWEEN ? AND ?", params[:date_one], :params[:date_two])
```

Comment: Thanks. Aren't the two queries same or is there any difference in it